# Set order on debugging variables list in PhpStorm

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

It is very stressful to use PhpStorm when inspecting the **Variables** in the **Debugger**. Is there any way to order them for the used arrays? I already searched a long time but it does not seem to help anything to get it in that way. So if you look on the picture I want **`#attached`** on the top and **`#user_category`** on the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot set custom order (where you will order them as you wish) but you can activate alphabetical sorting order -- just activate appropriate option in Debug tool window settings.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that works great. Puhh kind of hard to find. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't the default. What use is having them in some random order?

Comment: I think it's the order of when the vars are declared in their order.

Answer (score -2):

This answer is a bit late. Sorry for that.
A custom order could be etablished by creating variable watches. They will be shown at the top of the variables field.